# Connect to SQL Server database with appconfig

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database with `appconfig` but however I am getting the following error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
> occurred in System.Data.dll"

Here is my code:

```cs
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conectar"].ConnectionString);
```

`appconfig`:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="conectar" connectionString="server=servername;Integrated security=yes; Database=Base01"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The error is happening in the line:  `conexion.Open();`.

Edit: So sorry for providing poor information, Since you were asking it, here are the exepction details:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - could not open connection to sql server.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases - so every relational database is a "SQL database". Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/). Also: which programming language are you using? (Looks like C#)

Comment: The error message is "you had an error you did not handle" and that is totally true. Adding a try-catch code block and a breakpoint or exception logging in the catch would help you getting the error details that could help you. The info provided is kinda poor, we can only guess (if it was a web app running with the default application pool the user of the applicatio pool is likely missing as a user in the database)

Comment: Did you try to connect manually in *MS SqlServer Management Studio* to check the validity of those parameters?

Comment: Since you were asking for it,  i already added the exception details, is there more information i am not providing?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a number of reasons.
You might want to extract the exception and check what is happening.
Where ever you are calling the DB, add that code within the try.
Few reasons could be

1. DB is down
2. You don't have access
3. If azure is involved, check whether your IP address is not blocked by the firewall. But as I said, you might want to post the complete exception.

Comment: I would suggest answering the question once they have the information that could help giving a concrete answer (as you pointed out the question is missing important information). You could also edit the answer and add how to get the exception details, it would make your answer more useful

Comment: Since you were asking for it, i already added the exception details, is there more information i am not providing?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the SQL Server? IF yes, there probably is some issue with the app config. if no, You might wanna check if DB is up and working.